# Induction with unknown $n_0$

Tags: real-analysis

Proving by induction that $2^n\gt n^3 \; \; \; \forall n\geq 10$ isn't very difficult, but how would one prove by induction that $2^n\gt n^3 \; \; \; \forall n\geq n_0$ ? Meaning that one would have to find a suitable $n_0$ for which the base case of the inequality holds, without graphing tools.
The induction step $(n\to n+1)$ would be:
$$2^{n+1}\; =\; 2\cdot2^n$$$$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\gt 2 \cdot n^3=n^3+n^3 \;\;\;\text{(see basis step)}$$
$$\gt n^3+3n^2+3n+1 $$
$$=(n+1)^3$$
However I am unsure how to formulate the basis step with an unknown $n_0$.

Comment: You don't need to find the smallest possible $n_0$. Just try a few numbers and you'll soon lead yourself to one that's big enough.

Comment: @EthanBolker Sure, but I was hoping for a method that is less trial and error. I already know that the smallest possible $n_0$ is 10

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. We generally use inductive proofs because there's an easy way to find a base case, and in this case trial and error suffices. If there was an easy general way to find an $n_0$ which serves as a base case this method would serve as a proof and we wouldn't need induction.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the exact value of $n_0\in\Bbb R$ such that $2^{n_0}=n_0^3$ is not analytically possible but since $n_0\in\Bbb N$, we can find its **exact** value by hand. Note that$$2^9=512<729=9^3\\2^{10}=1024>1000=10^3$$therefore $n_0$ **must be greater than or equal to $10$** for our base of indunction to hold. Also note that if $$f(x)=2^x\\g(x)=x^3$$then $f'(x)>g'(x)$for all $x\ge 10$, leading to this result that $f(x)$ grows super faster than $g(x)$ for $x\ge 10$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the binomial theorem: for $n \ge 4$

$$ 2^n = (1+1)^n \ge {n \choose 4} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}$$
We want this $> n^3$, but we don't want too much work. So let's see:
if $n \ge 6$ we have $n-3 \ge n/2$, so 
$$ n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) \ge n (n/2)^3 = n^4/8$$
so now we want
$$ \frac{n^4}{8 \cdot 24} > n^3$$
which is true if $n > 8 \cdot 24 = 192 $.